# Finding limits of integration for double integral

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Given a region where the $x$ limits are $-1< x<1$ and $0< y<\sqrt{4-x^2}$, with the option of converting into polar coordinates, i.e. the function $(x,y)$ can be replaced by $r^2$.

I'm finding it tricky to get the limits for $r$. The region $R$ would look like a semi-circle bounded below by the $x$-axis, with radius $2$. But the $x$ limits are $1$ and $-1$, so the region we want is inside of this semi-circle?

Is it possible to approximate this as a rectangle and take the $r$-limits as $-1,1$ and $\theta$ as $0,\pi$?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$R$ can be seen as the disjoint union of three sets, $R=R_1\cup R_2\cup R_3$, where
\begin{align*}
R_1&=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<\theta<\pi/3,0<r<\sec\theta\}\\
R_2&=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\pi/3\le\theta<2\pi/3,0<r<2\}\\
R_3&=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:2\pi/3\le\theta<\pi,0< r <|\sec \theta|\}
\end{align*}